# How to output {gtsummary} tables as images?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to output {gtsummary} tables (specifically `tbl_regression()` output) as images. I am using `kableExtra::as_image()` but the result is not very pretty. A reprex is below but I don't have the reputation to post an image.

Is there a way to programmatically get an image of the `tbl_regression()` output? On the [{gtsummary} github site](https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary), there are very nice table images in the README but I am not sure if they were created manually or with code as I don't see any functions that extracted them.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(kableExtra)

m_linear <-
    lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

gtsummary::tbl_regression(m_linear) %>%
    gtsummary::as_kable() %>%
    kableExtra::as_image(file = "t.png")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The images on the website were printed using the [{gt} package](https://gt.rstudio.com/) from RStudio (which we love), and they have a function to save tables ([`gt::gtsave()`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/gtsave.html)) that works beautifully with {gtsummary} tables.

You can use the following steps to save a {gtsummary} table using {gt}:

```r
library(gtsummary)

# make model and tbl_regression object
m_linear <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
t1 <- tbl_regression(m_linear)

# Use function from gt package to save table, after converting to 
# gt object using as_gt()
gt::gtsave(as_gt(t1), file = file.path(tempdir(), "temp.png"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope this works for you, good luck!

Comment: This returns `PhantomJS` not found error.

Comment: @Mandalorian just install it with `webshot::install_phantomjs()`.

Comment: Is there a way to change the output size?