# Export full table image in R when the plot create by gt package

Tags: r, gt

I don't think this is more a coding issue, as I have a table that I create under gt package.
When I want to export it into JPEG, the table seems to be too long and the JPEG that exported only go as long as my screen size go.

Any idea on how to export the full table into jpeg?
I try to search for a solution online but I don't seems to be able to find it.

Comment: try `gtsave`. refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751172/how-to-output-gtsummary-tables-as-images

Comment: Agree with commenter. I routinely output pretty large `gt` tables with `gtsave()`.